# Lists of lists into lists of tuples

Tags: file, split, tuples, txt

After being given a huge amount of .txt files, how can I break down the lines of the text files into tuples of 3 which overlap each other? I have broken down the lines by white space as shown below, which I think is correct.

As an example, if the list of words are “the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog” and “n” is 3, the output should be
[('the', 'quick', 'brown'),
('quick', 'brown', 'fox'),
('brown', 'fox', 'jumps'),
('fox', 'jumps', 'over'),
('jumps', 'over', 'the'),
('over', 'the', 'lazy'),
('the', 'lazy', 'dog')]

TIA

```
n=3
word_list=[]   #Initialising to empty
filename = "filename.txt"
with open(filename,"r") as file_object: #
    for line in file_object:  #for loop to read every line in .txt file
        word_list=line.split()  #spliting the lines by "white space"
        new_list = [word_list[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(word_list), n)]
        tuple(new_list)
        print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create ngrams you could e.g. also use a package which implements this in a fast and efficient way

```
from nltk import ngrams
s = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
ngrams = ngrams(s.split(), 3)
for word in ngrams :
  print(word)
```

This generates the following output

```
('the', 'quick', 'brown')
('quick', 'brown', 'fox')
('brown', 'fox', 'jumps')
('fox', 'jumps', 'over')
('jumps', 'over', 'the')
('over', 'the', 'lazy')
('the', 'lazy', 'dog')
```

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not allowed to import any packages :( it needs to be done manually, but thank you